# Is there any way to change default height of slider

Tags: css, reactjs, slider, package

I am using nuka-carousel slider but can't change the default slider height to 760px. Here is the link of that carousel. I tried to add initialSlideHeight but it does not help me.
https://reactjsexample.com/a-pure-reactjs-carousel-component/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use `heightMode` and `initialSlideHeight`, but I didn't have success either. As well as, changing the carousel' imgs height.

I searched a little bit at the repo, and found some issues that may causing this problem. Like this one:

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/nuka-carousel/issues/457

Maybe you should try to find another solution. Good luck!